# Getting Error:ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I tried to solving this problem by running "`Install Certificates.command`" under Application/Python3.12 folder and running `pip install -upgrade certifi` but still got the error

When I trying to run the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
```

I got the following exception:

ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)

Here is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1454, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1075, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1346, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lorenliu/PROGRAM/NeuralFuck/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/data_utils.py", line 347, in get_file
    urlretrieve(origin, fpath, DLProgbar())
  File "/Users/lorenliu/PROGRAM/NeuralFuck/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/data_utils.py", line 85, in urlretrieve
    response = urlopen(url, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lorenliu/PROGRAM/NeuralFuck/venv/a.py", line 6, in <module>
    (training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lorenliu/PROGRAM/NeuralFuck/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/datasets/fashion_mnist.py", line 93, in load_data
    paths.append(get_file(fname, origin=base + fname, cache_subdir=dirname))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lorenliu/PROGRAM/NeuralFuck/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/data_utils.py", line 351, in get_file
    raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Then I tried following way found from StackOverflow:

```
import ssl
import certifi
from urllib.request import urlopen
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist



urlopen(dataResult = mnist.load_data(), context=ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where()))

((training_images, training_labels),  (test_images, test_labels)) = dataResult
```

but doesn't help at all

Comment: Have you found an answer?  I am facing the same thing.